# How one concludes that Gauss law is valid here or not and line integral of $E$ is zero without using curl?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

I encountered this problem while considering option (b) below. I took the curl and found to be zero, but is there some more elegant way to show that (b) is correct? Also, for option (c), I can make the conclusion for the spherical case, but not for other cases. Can anyone tell how to validate/invalidate Gauss' law in other cases?

> In another world, instead of the Coulomb's law, electric force $\vec{F}$ on a point like charge $q$ due to another point like charge $Q$ is found to obey the following law.
> $$\vec{F} = \frac{Qq\left(1-\sqrt{\alpha r}\right)}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 r^3}\hat{r}$$
> Here $\alpha$ is a positive constant and $\vec{r}$ is the position vector of charge $q$ relative to the chrage $Q$.
>
> (a) Electric field due to a point charge $Q$ is $\vec{E} = \frac{Q\left(1-\sqrt{\alpha r}\right)}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 r^3}\hat{r}$
>
> (b) Line integral of this electric field $\oint\vec{E}\cdot\textrm{d}\vec{l}$ over a closed path is also zero as in our world.
>
> (c) Gauss' law $\oint \vec{E}\cdot\textrm{d}\vec{s} = \frac{q_{enclosed}}{\varepsilon_0}$ also holds true for this electric field.
>
> (d) All the above statements are true but this electric field is not conservative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For option (b), the correctness of this equation is equivalent to whether the force is a conservative force, or whether the new field is a conservative field. We can see that the direction of the force is determined by $\hat{r}$ (which means the force is a repulsive force) and the magnitude of the new force is determined by $Q,q$ and $r$ (both $\sqrt{r}$ and $r^3$ can only determine the magnitude, but not the direction), so we can easily discover that the word done by this force is irrelative to the route, so the option (b) is correct.

For option (c), we can do some deduction
$$
d\phi=\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{S}=\frac{Q(1-\sqrt{\alpha r})}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^3}dS\cos{\theta}
$$
Then due to the property of solid angle, $d\Omega=\frac{dS_\perp}{r^2}=\frac{dS\cos{\theta}}{r^2}$, we have
$$
d\phi=\frac{Q(1-\sqrt{\alpha r})}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r}d\Omega
$$
Then we use the another property of solid angle, a closed surface's solid angle to a point inside it is $4\pi$, we have
$$
\oint\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{S}=\oint d\phi=\oint \frac{Q(1-\sqrt{\alpha r})}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r}d\Omega
$$
If option (c) is correct, we can find that $\frac{1-\sqrt{\alpha r}}{r}=1$, that can not be satisfied. So option (c) is not correct.

Hope that will be helpful.

Comment: This doesnt answer my problem at all  , i asked for some different form of electric field given by above problem. And by your way both b and c would turn out to be correct but its not true

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I will reedit my answer.

Comment: I have completed reediting my answer.

Comment: Still one thing Sir part B i didnt get from u r saying that force is only a functiom of Q r and q , how does that imply B is correct. For C r u considering a spherical charge distribution not ig anytype of shape ?

Comment: For option (b), we should prove that the work done by the force is irrelative to the route the object moves. We can discover that the magnitude of force is determined by the object's absolute position. That means when you are calculating the work, you needn't consider the relative displacement (such as the friction force, that is a non-conservative force), you can simply do the integration and use the basic law of integration to calculate (that means the work done is determined by the start and end point).

Comment: If you want a more general and theoretical explanation for option (b), there is. The necessary and sufficient condition of a force being a conservative force is $\nabla \times \vec{F}=0$, you can do this calculation to prove option (b). This is the method parsa639 offering, you can refer to his answer.

Comment: For option (c), I give the situation of a point charge. However, for a charge in all shapes, you can simply do an integration, which means consider it a combination of considerable point charges. Then you will see the conclusion remains the same.

Comment: But one thing Sir ,still position vector i got it but in that electric field term there is 1-√r term which depends on position (not as position vector) so will not the work done may be not conservative ?

Comment: I have reedited this part. Only the term $\hat{r}$ can determine the direction.

Answer (score 2):

We can calculate curl and divergence of the given field to show that statements (c) and (d) are not true:
$$
 \nabla \times \vec{E} = \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \nabla \times (\frac{1-\sqrt{\alpha r}}{r^3} \hat{r}) = 0
 $$
$$
 \nabla \cdot \vec{E} = \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \nabla \cdot (\frac{1-\sqrt{\alpha r}}{r^3} \hat{r}) = \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^4} (\frac 12 \sqrt{\alpha r} -1 )
 $$
so we can conclude that Gauss's law doesn't hold true here and that this field is conservative.
As a hint I want to say that if Gauss's law held here it should have had this form:
$$
    \nabla \cdot \vec{E} = \frac {\rho}{\alpha \epsilon_0}  
 $$
due to dimensional constraints.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way starts with “this looks like it should be a conservative force and therefore should have a potential energy function.” If that's true then you can do any line integral from point A to point B by taking the difference of the potential energies, and then any closed line integral can be divided into two paths, from A to B to A again, and the total difference of potential energy is zero, without invoking the curl theorem.

Comment: For that Sir , dont we still need to know the potential function by integrating this electric field ? Then only we can checking by difference right the potential energies u r talkiing of isnt ?

Comment: Or Sir how u thought that this force seems like conservative force from just by looking ?