# What type of electric field different from what is obeyed from Coulombs law is always obeying the Gauss law?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, coulombs-law

Follow up question from this : [How one concludes that Gauss law is valid here or not and line integral of $E$ is zero without using curl?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/623843/293182) i thought of if electric field is not of form kq/r^2 from a point charge but instead some modified form like k'q/r^3( radial )or like kq/r^3 ( tangetial always ) etc.. then in which cases its guaranteed that gauss law will be followed?

Comment: None of your proposed are obeyed the Gauss's Law.

Comment: Yes Sir , i meant so in general what type of field can follow gauss law and what not like for example a field like Kq(1-r)/r^3( radial) etc.... ( I asked what property  those electric field needs to follow in order to follow gauss law)

Comment: Does radial field is one of the conditions ? And something more to it ?

Comment: It is dimension dependence. For 3-d space, radial field and $1/r^2$ is the condition to meet the Gauss's Law. Since in 3-d the area is porportional to $r^2$ which cancels the $1/r^2$ radial factor.

Comment: In 2-d space, the area (line segment) is proportional to $r$, therefore a $1/r$ radial field will cancel the area, make the 2-d "area" integral of field flux constant independent the size of the 2-d "area". In general for $n$-d space, the radial field of $1/r^{n-1}$ will lead to surface integral of the field flux independent of the enclosed volume size.

Comment: So radial is must condition right Sir ?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know.

Comment: Alright ty Sir.